# SQL Server - float vs varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar, sqldatatypes

In SQL Server, I have decimal data to be stored in a table (which is never used for joins or filtering). This decimal data is variable - 80% of the time it has single digit values (1, 4, 5) and remaining 20% are with 16 digit decimals (0.8999999761581421, 3.0999999046325684).

I am wondering If I can save any storage space going with `varchar` instead of `float`, or if I should stick with `float` since this is numeric data?

Comment: `decimal` <> `float`. By *"I have decimal data"* do you *really* mean *"I have float data"*? If not, is your data actually a `decimal` and not a `float`? Either way, never use a `varchar` to store numerical data.

Comment: @varun . . . This looks suspicious to me.  I am guessing the integers are codes of some sort and the decimals are real values -- and that the data should  not be mixed in a single column.

Comment: Regardless of whether you keep `FLOAT` or go with `DECIMAL`, never use a string type to store numerical data, regardless of storage considerations. The *only* time that might be appropriate is if you have a very specific need to store data received from an external system *exactly* as you got it, character for character, even if it also has a numeric value. This is clearly not one of those cases. If storage was even a concern at all, you should consider things like row and page compression before the data type, simply because mixing up strings and numbers is such a huge source of pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Always** use the **most appropriate** datatype! Since this is clearly **numerical** data - use a numerical type. This will allow to e.g. sum the values, order by those values - those are numbers - so treat and store them as such!!

If you need to support fractions, you *could* use `FLOAT` or `REAL`, but those are notorious for rounding errors etc. Using `DECIMAL(p,s)` avoids those pitfalls - it's stable, it's precise, not prone to rounding errors. So that would be my logical choice.

See the [official MS docs for `DECIMAL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for your details on how to define the `p` (precision - total number of digits overall) and `s` (scale - number of digits *after* the decimal point).

And btw: those are stored in **fewer** bytes that a `varchar` column large enough to hold these values would be!

Comment: I agree with you if this numeric data is used for any numeric calculations. but it is not. it is one of the scientific values and just displayed in the report as is. so, would you still recommend to go with decimal over varchar? because my understanding is float is going to take fixed number of bytes unlike varchar. thank you!

Comment: @varun: ***YES!!!!!!*** And as I mentioned - `decimal` will most likely use **FEWER** space than a comparable `varchar` - all the more reason to pick the **numerical** datatype

Comment: @varun: just wait until you suddenly have to sort your `SELECT` by one of these columns - if you use a `varchar` for this - **good luck!** - this just causes endless and needless grief and headaches - **don't do it**. If it looks like a number, quacks like a number, smells like a number - **IT IS** a number and then you should by all means **treat and store it** as a number

Answer (score 5):

Here's an interesting observation:

Start with the mathematical value `0.9`

Convert that to a binary number.  For the same reason that 1/3 cannot be expressed in a finite number of digits in base 10, the number 0.9 cannot be expressed in a finite number of digits in base 2. The exact mathematical value is:

`0.1 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100` ...  with the "1100" repeating forever.

Let's store this value in an IEEE-754 single-precision floating-point value. (In SQL Server, this is called `REAL` type).  To do that we have to round to 23 significant bits.  The result is:

```
0.1 1100 1100 1100 1100 1100 11
```

Convert this to its exact decimal equivalent, you get this:

```
0.89999997615814208984375
```

Round that to 16 places after the decimal point.  You get:

```
0.8999999761581421
```

Which is coincidentally the value you show as your example.

If you do the same thing to `3.1`, you get `3.0999999046325684`

Is it possible that all your inputs are simply numbers with one digit after the decimal point, which have been stored as a floating-point value, and then converted back into decimal?